# Crossrider API not ready to receive events?

Tags: crossrider

I'm trying to trigger an event on my crossrider extension.  Using the code below the event never gets to the extension.  If I put a timeout and wait 5 seconds it does.  So is there a way to detect when the extension\api is ready to receive events?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    var x = 'xxxxx';

   $('body').fireExtensionEvent('eventName', { key: 'token-' + x });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CrossriderAPI.isAppInstalled](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/CrossriderAPI).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://w9u6a2p6.ssl.hwcdn.net/plugins/javascripts/crossriderAPI.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Replace XXXXX with the extension id
    var extId = "XXXXX";

    // Once the page is ready
    $(function() {
        CrossriderAPI.isAppInstalled(extId, function(isInstalled) {
            // Displays true if the extension is installed; otherwise false
            var x = 'xxxxx';
            $('body').fireExtensionEvent('eventName', { key: 'token-' + x });
        });
    });
</script>
```

[**Disclosure:** I am a Crossrider employee]